# Call a function that located in .jslib file using my C# code- Unity3D webGL

Tags: javascript, c#, dom

Can I trigger a javasript function from my C# unity code?
I want a javascript function that uses **DOM** to be executed by my C# unity code.

Can I use DOM in Unity webGL ?